# how to read a all data between string1 to string2 from test.txt file in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have to read a text file using shell scrip from value `abc` to `pqr` and store that data to `new.txt`

Note: text file contain multiple block of value `abc` to `pqr`. So I have to read all block one by one.

In linux
I am searching a particular value from text file and I am getting text. i.e above and below 20 lines from the searched value.
I am storing that data in new text file `output.txt`

Command:

```
Str=$(grep -i -B 20 -A 20 "searching_value" test.txt)
echo "${str}" >> output.txt
```

Comment: My best guess is `awk`.

Comment: Try `sed -n '/abc/,/pqr/p' test.txt` to filter all blocks with one command.

Comment: Maybe remove the `sh` tag and replace with `awk` if `awk` is acceptable to you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example input and the expected output, formatted as code blocks. I suggest to remove one/some of your tags and add `unix-text-processing`.